# Fair quantiles with lots of same values?

Tags: r, statistics, frequency

Doing rfm analysis. i want to divide ranks by 5. i've done this ok. The problem is when i try the quantile function by 5 in the `frequency` part to divide buyers by "great customer" if they buy often with rank 5, 'good' if they buy kind of less (rank 4) and so on, the fact that large number of buyers have bought 1 time in a year makes the quantiles like this:

```
f=quantile(cust$freq,probs=seq(0,1,0.20))


  0%  20%  40%  60%  80% 100% 
   1    1    1    2    4  170
```

So i tried with unique values but the result will not consider the frequency of people with that habit so it's not right because what most do must be considered as well.

Anyway, the frequency is distributed like this:

```
table(cust$freq)

 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13 
68949 32476 18125 11363  7646  5248  3594  2503  1922  1359  1061   778   595 
   14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26 
  433   348   275   221   171   104    94    74    54    59    36    37    23 
   27    28    29    30    31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38    39 
   15    21    26    13    11    11    10     6     8     1     7     5     1 
   40    41    42    43    45    46    47    48    53    57    60    73    94 
    4     4     4     4     2     2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 
  170 
    1
```

The question is how to divide it by considering **both** the fact that **a lot** of people buy once in the year but also focus on the large range of people's habits by showing more diverse number of days (frequency) per quartile to rank customers from 5 to 1 later.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `cut` with `breaks` specified as the `quantile` and then take the `table` i.e. `with(cust, table(cut(freq, breaks = quantile(freq, probs=seq(0,1,0.20)))))`

Comment: It says: `'breaks' are not unique`. Tried using the unique function prior to quantile but it isn't what i am trying

Comment: As you didn't provide a reproducible example, it is difficult to help.  It doesn't have an error using `set.seed(24);
cust <- data.frame(freq = sample(170, 1e5, replace = TRUE))`

Comment: Here's the dataset [link] (http://www.mediafire.com/file/2zd6e345b89j4jt/stackov)

Comment: Perhaps manually chosen interval would work? As in, e.g., `table(cut(cust$freq, breaks = c(1, 5, 10, 30, 50, Inf)))`. That helps because the distribution of frequencies is very nonlinear.

Comment: i've fixed it with something similar.thanks you for trying though

Comment: Feel free to post and accept your own answer then.